# Finding the correct return type in java

Tags: java, methods, try-catch, return-type

I am having trouble making the correct return procedure. I am suppose to increment the current total for the amount type specified by the first parameter by the amount specified in the second parameter.I got some issues. Please help me.

```
public void newValue(char amountType, double amount)
{
  if (amount <=0) // if amount entered is invalid
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The amount needs to be 0 or larger "+amountType+" "+amount);

  if (amountType !='T' || amountType !='D' || amountType !='E') // if letter for the amount type is invalid (T,D, or E)
  totalTicketSales += amount;
  totalMoneyDonated += amount;
  totalExpenses += amount;

  throw new IllegalArgumentException("That is an invalid letter value. "+amountType+" "+amount
            + "The data will be ignored"); 

    currentAmount = amountType + amount;  //this is where my issue is
}
```

So here is the latest. I tried to make some changes to this based on your feedback.

```
public double newValue(char amountType, double amount)
{
    double currentAmount = amountType + amount; 

  if (amount <=0) // if amount entered is invalid
  //I get an error here on this exception
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The amount needs to be 0 or larger "+amountType+" "+amount);


  if (amountType !='T' || amountType !='D' || amountType !='E') // if letter for the amount type is invalid (T,D, or E)
  {
      totalTicketSales += amount;
  totalMoneyDonated += amount;
  totalExpenses += amount;

  throw new IllegalArgumentException("That is an invalid letter value. "+amountType+" "+amount
            + "The data will be ignored"); 
  }
     return currentAmount;
}
```

Comment: Use brackets `{ }` when constructing multiple line `if statements`

Comment: Would this help my issue with the return value?

Comment: Your method is declared to ***not*** return anything (`void`), so the `return` value is superfluous.  You need to clarify what you want to return, if anything.

Comment: Okay. So you made changes. Does the problem persist? Is there a new problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. The if syntax in Java is this:

   ```
   if (Statement) {
       sentence1;
       sentence2;
       ...
   }
   ```

   If you have only one sentence then you don't need brackets, but if you have multiple lines inside your if statement, you need to enclose them between brackets. So, you need to enclose your second if between brackets:

   ```
   if (amountType !='T' || amountType !='D' || amountType !='E') // if letter for the amount type is invalid (T,D, or E)
   {    
       totalTicketSales += amount;
       totalMoneyDonated += amount;
       totalExpenses += amount;

       throw new IllegalArgumentException("That is an invalid letter value. " + amountType + " "+ amount + "The data will be ignored"); 
   }
   ```
2. Also, you are adding a double to a char. This can't be done.

   ```
   currentAmount = amountType + amount;  // YOU CAN'T ADD A DOUBLE TO A CHAR
   ```
3. You are returning "nothing" in your method. Void method means that you are not going to return anything. If you want to return a double variable, you need to change yout method header to:

   ```
   public double newValue(char amountType, double amount){
       code;
       ...
   }
   ```

This is a code example to add an amount to an initialValue. If opType is T, D or E, then it throws an exception (Based on the code you've posted).

```
public double addAmount (double initialValue, double amount, char opType) {
    if (amount <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount must be > 0.");

    if (opType == 'T' || opType == 'D' || opType == 'E')
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid opType operation.");

    return initialValue + amount; // Now you are returning a double + double = double
}
```

Comment: You missed the other two major problems, which are (1)  the test (`&&` instead of `||`), and (2) the `char`+`double`) return on a `void` method (or is that 2 issues by itself).  Explain those as well and I'll upvote.

Comment: Why `&&` instead `||`? He is testing if the char is T or D or E to throw an exception.

Comment: The big problem there is that he is adding a double variable to a char, and this is going to throw a compilation error.

Comment: The OP's intent is very unclear. and it is risky to provide an answer by guessing at intent. Sometimes you can guess with 90% certainty... in this case I'd say any guess is <50% until some questions are answered.

Comment: `currentAmount = amountType + amount;`  I believe this is the big issue for me on my code.

Comment: Yes! You are adding a double variable to a char. This is like: B + 2.0 = ¿?. You need to change amountType variable to be a double and also you need to return a double in your method (not a void).

Comment: can double only be added to double? or can other variable types be added as well? is char the only exception?

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see clearly your errors. And yes, double only can be added to double variables (you can't add a double to a int for example, or you can't add a double to a String).

Comment: So i should change the parameters in my method? This means i cannot return anything unless its changed?

Comment: You are adding a double to a char but now in another line `double currentAmount = amountType + amount;` You can not add a double to a char. This is like going to bank and you want to add the letter 'B' into yout bank account. This makes no sense. Your bank account has money (double for example) and you can only add money (double) to it. I will update my answer with a code to perform what you are trying to do correctly.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the right code to add an amount to an initial value depending on the operation type, hope it helps! @Luke8h :)